# Aggregating sequence of connected events

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have events like this in my log

```
{type:"approval_revokation", approval_id=22}
{type:"approval", request_id=12, approval_id=22}
{type:"control3", request_id=12}
{type:"control2", request_id=12}
{type:"control1", request_id=12}
{type:"request", request_id=12 requesting_user="user1"}
{type:"registration", userid="user1"}
```

I would like to do a search that aggregates one bucket for each approval_id containing all events connected to it as above. As you see there is not a single id field that can be used throughout the events, but they are all connected in a chain.

The reason I would like this is to feed this into a anomaly detector to verify things like that all controls where executed and validate registration event for a eventual approval.

Can this be done using aggregation or are there any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no single unique "glue" parameter to tie these events together, I'm afraid the only choice is a brute-force [map-reduce iterator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) on all the docs in the index.

After ingesting the above events:

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"events","_type":"_doc"}}
{"type":"approval_revokation","approval_id":22}
{"index":{"_index":"events","_type":"_doc"}}
{"type":"approval","request_id":12,"approval_id":22}
{"index":{"_index":"events","_type":"_doc"}}
{"type":"control3","request_id":12}
{"index":{"_index":"events","_type":"_doc"}}
{"type":"control2","request_id":12}
{"index":{"_index":"events","_type":"_doc"}}
{"type":"control1","request_id":12}
{"index":{"_index":"events","_type":"_doc"}}
{"type":"request","request_id":12,"requesting_user":"user1"}
{"index":{"_index":"events","_type":"_doc"}}
{"type":"registration","userid":"user1"}
```

we can link them together like so:

```
POST events/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "log_groups": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.groups = [];",
        "map_script": """
          int fetchIndex(List groups, def key, def value, def backup_key) {
            if (key == null || value == null) {
              // nothing to search
              return -1
            }
            return IntStream.range(0, groups.size())
               .filter(i -> groups.get(i)['docs']
                                  .stream()
                                  .anyMatch(_doc -> _doc.get(key) == value 
                                                      || (backup_key != null
                                                            && _doc.get(backup_key) == value)))
               .findFirst()
               .orElse(-1);
          }
          
          def approval_id = doc['approval_id'].size() != 0 
                              ? doc['approval_id'].value
                              : null;
          def request_id = doc['request_id'].size() != 0 
                              ? doc['request_id'].value
                              : null;
          def requesting_user = doc['requesting_user.keyword'].size() != 0 
                                  ? doc['requesting_user.keyword'].value
                                  : null;
          def userid = doc['userid.keyword'].size() != 0 
                        ? doc['userid.keyword'].value
                        : null;
          
          HashMap valueMap = ['approval_id':approval_id,
                              'request_id':request_id,
                              'requesting_user':requesting_user,
                              'userid':userid];
          
          def found = false;
          
          for (def entry : valueMap.entrySet()) {
            def field = entry.getKey();
            def value = entry.getValue();

            def backup_key = field == 'userid' 
                                        ? 'requesting_user'
                                        : field == 'requesting_user'
                                            ? 'userid'
                                            : null;
            
            def found_index = fetchIndex(state.groups, field, value, backup_key);
            
            if (found_index != -1) {
              state.groups[found_index]['docs'].add(params._source);
              if (approval_id != null) {
                state.groups[found_index]['approval_id'] = approval_id;
              }
              found = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          
          if (!found) {
            HashMap nextInLine = ['docs': [params._source]];
            if (approval_id != null) {
              nextInLine['approval_id'] = approval_id;
            }
            state.groups.add(nextInLine);
          }

        """,
        "combine_script": "return state",
        "reduce_script": "return states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returning the grouped events + the inferred `approval_id`:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "log_groups" : {
    "value" : [
      {
        "groups" : [
          {
            "docs" : [
              {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...} 
            ],
            "approval_id" : 22
          },
          { ... }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that such scripts [are going to be quite slow](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scripts-and-search-speed.html), esp. when run on large numbers of events.